# numpy.apply_along_axis truncates strings because it infers wrong dtype '<U1'

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I don't know how to return string with dtype U3

I want to:

1. apply_along_axis to my_array
2. for every row, return a string

```py
def my_function(x):
    return x[2]
my_array = np.array([[1,1,"A"],[1,1,"BBB"], [1,1,"CCC"]])
np.apply_along_axis(my_function, axis=1, arr=my_array)
```

I expect the output of:
`array(['A', 'BBB', 'CCC'], dtype='<U3')`
but the actual output is 
`array(['A', 'B', 'C'], dtype='<U1')`

because first element ('A') has fixed-size U1 every next elements are truncate to U1 ('BBB' -> 'B').

Do you know how to change code to string with for example dtype U3?

Comment: Often `apply_along_axis` is over kill.  In your example, `np.array([x[2] for x in my_array]) ` is 10x faster.   `apply` is most convenient when the array is 3d or larger, and iterating over 2 or more dimensions looks messy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this (though there probably should be a better way):

```py
import numpy as np

def my_function(x):
    return np.array(x[2], dtype='<U3')

my_array = np.array([[1,1,"A"],[1,1,"BBB"], [1,1,"CCC"]])
np.apply_along_axis(my_function, axis=1, arr=my_array)
```

Comment: If `my_function` accepts a `dtype` parameter, it can be passed to via `apply_along_axis`.  It's a good idea to read the code for `apply_along_axis`.

Answer (score 0):

For this particular use case, you can use slicing, i.e.

```
my_array[:, 2]
```

and avoid apply_along_axis altogether. But I agree that inferring the type from the first application of the function is troublesome. There is also an [issue](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/8352) for it.

By the way: The numbers in your array get converted to strings, but that results in a less-than-optimal type of `<U21`. If you directly make them strings, you get `<U3`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I simplified my real problem with apply_along_axis and returning string (so my_array[:, 2] is correct answer but not for my real problem) . May be i should be more precise with explain my problem. This is my first question on stackoverflow :).